# Сортировка строк и перенос из файла в файл

Tags: c++, файлы, строки

Всем привет! Задача: на входе файл со строками. Строки из этого файла переносятся в массив типа char, затем этот массив сортируется по алфавиту и переписывается в другой файл столбиком.
Пример работы программы:

#### infile.txt

```
Csdf
Bsdf
Asdf
```

#### onfile.txt

```
Asdf
Bsdf
Csdf
```

Мой код (не работает). Прошу посодействовать:

```
#include <fstream>  
#include <iostream> 
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
protected:
    char *mass;
public:
    int countElements() //узнаем размер входного вайла
    {
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("D:/Job/Debug/infile.txt", ios::binary);
        infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
        int n = (int)infile.tellg();
        infile.close();
        return n;
    }
    void fileToArray(int n) // переносим данные из входного файла в массив 
    {
        mass = new char[n];
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("D:/Job/Debug/infile.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
        if (!infile) cout << "Ошибка, файл не найден" << endl;
        infile.read(mass, n);
        infile.close();
    }
    void arrayToFile(int n) //переносим из массива в файл
    {
        ofstream outfile;
        outfile.open("D:/Job/Debug/onfile.txt", ios::out);
        if (!outfile) cout << "Ошибка, файл не найден" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (('0' <= mass[i] && mass[i] <= '9') || ('a' <= mass[i] && mass[i] <= 'z') || ('A' <= mass[i] && mass[i] <= 'Z'))
            {
                outfile << mass[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        outfile.close();
        delete[] mass;
    }
    void sort_s_a(int n)//сортируем массив строк по алфавиту 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(mass[i], mass[j])>0)
                {
                    char *temp;
                    *temp = mass[i];
                    mass[i] = mass[j];
                    mass[j] = *temp;
                }
            }
        }

    }
};
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    Test test;
    int n = test.countElements();//вынес в main() чтобы избежать вложенностей
    test.fileToArray(n);
    test.sort_s_a(n);
    test.arrayToFile(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если уж вы хотите создавать класс, то инициализируйте в конструкторе члены, в деструкторе освобождайте выделенную память, а не делайте это в членах...

Если хотите работать с массивом - то потом вам нужно пройтись по нему, заменив все `'\n'` (ну, или `"\r\n"`) нулями, создать соответствующий массив указателей и сортировать его в соответствии со строками, на которые он указывает. Или изначально работать с `char ** mass`.

В `strcmp` нужно передавать указатели на строки, а не символы.

Потоки можно не закрывать - при выходе из функций они закроются сами.

И вообще, раз уж это C++, а не смесь <s>французского с нижегородским</s> С и С++, то я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in("infile.txt");
    vector<string> vs;
    string s;
    while(getline(in,s)) vs.push_back(s);
    sort(vs.begin(),vs.end());
    ofstream on("onfile.txt");
    copy(vs.begin(),vs.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(on,"\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну и измените путь к файлу на 
 `D://Job//Debug//infile.txt`

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ответ - как ваеш решение отвечает на вопрос ТС? Пока непонятно, как изменением пути к файлу можно сортировать строки в нем.